# inserting data from HDFS files using apache spark installed on same cluster to DSE cassandra table in another cluster

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, cassandra, datastax, spark-cassandra-connector

We have Spark 1.6 installed on Hadoop cluster 2.8. and we have a separate Datastax Cassandra cluster 4.8.6 (C* 3.x and spark 1.4.2). We need to copy data from HDFS files into DSE cassandra table. In our current job we are submitting a spark job (spark-submit in standalone mode) on HDFS+Spark cluster which loads data into DSE cassandra table (separate cluster). in this job we are connecting to cassandra cluster and using available Spark cluster there. We are trying to find a way to use Spark resources (spark-submit Yarn mode) available on Hadoop cluster and write to cassandra table. Is it possible to use just Spark cluster in Hadoop cluster and load into external cassandra cluster? Something like loading data into RDD or Dataframe using hadoop Spark and then connecting to  Cassandra to load data? based on my understanding and research so far, it is not possible. any inputs?---

same sample code (not working)-

```
class LoadData() extends Serializable {

def ReadHDFSFile() {

val HDFSUrl = "hdfs://hadoopcluster"
val hdfsFile = HDFSUrl+"/testHDFSFile"

// Connecting to Spark on HDFS+Spark cluster
val conf = new SparkConf()
conf.setAppName("DataScala")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "false").option("inferSchema", "true").option("delimiter", "\u0001").load(hdfsFile)
df.registerTempTable("testTable")

// now connect to external cassandra cluster
try{

  val cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoints(CassandraNodes).withQueryOptions(new QueryOptions().setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.ONE)).withCredentials(CassandraUser, CassandraPassword).build
  val session= cluster.connect()
   // is it possible to use DataFrame from different sc to load data into cassandra?
   session.execute("INSERT INTO CassandraTableName SELECT 1, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, null, C8, C9, null FROM testTable")

} catch  {
  case e: Exception => println(e.fillInStackTrace())

}
```